# Django admin, how to use model to add fields into another

Tags: python, django, model

I want to create a class that can be extended by users. I think in something similar to:

```
class User(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class UserAttributes(model.Models):
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attribute_value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

What I want is to create an UserAttribute when I'm editing/creating an User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inlines model to show form in the admin.

```
class UserAttributeinline(admin.TabularInline)
    model = UserAttributes


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [UserAttributesinline]
```

Comment: Thanks, I change a little bit the question because I think it's more clear now. But, there's something about your solution that I don't understand, and it's why I see tree input fields, it's django default?